# Exclude cases from a calculation in mongodb to not divide by zero, maximum value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to do a calculation, and excluding the cases when "n" is zero

What I need is:

the maximun value of all cases value/n, excluding cases where n=0

```
  { "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc1", "value" : "1","n" : "1"}
  { "_id" : 2, "item" : "abc1", "value" : "4" ,"n" : "2"}
  { "_id" : 3, "item" : "abc1", "value" : "11" ,"n" : "0"}
  { "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc1", "value" : "12" ,"n" : "3"}
  { "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz1", "value" : "2" ,"n" : "0"}
```

so in this case, I will have

Division will be = {1,2,4}

so the maximun will be 4

So far, I manage to get the list of cases and calculate the division, I flag the cases where n is equal to zero, but I'm lost now.

```
db.collection.aggregate([      
{"$project":
       {
      "item": "$item",
      "valuet": "$value", 
      "n": "$n", 
      "max": { $max: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$n", 0 ] }, "N/A", {"$divide":["$value", "$n"]} ] }},                        
 }                             
 },                                
{"$sort": {"max":-1}}                             
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

`$match` to filter the `n` values with 0 and `$group` remaining documents to find the max.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{n:{$ne:0}}}, 
{$group:{_id:null, max:{$max: {$divide:["$value", "$n"]}}}}])
```

Sample Response

```
{ "_id" : null, "max" : 4 }
```